# Is there a place to run psychopy scripts online?

Tags: python, psychopy

Is there any place where you can run an online experiment by uploading a psychopy script (Python 2.7)?

Best,
Simon

Comment: Have you tried google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python scripts can not be run online, however the major feature of recently-released PsychoPy version 3 is the ability to generate Javascript experiments that can be run online from the https://pavlovia.org server. You can, however, use the Pavlovia server to host and share Python experiment code files online, but that is just for storage and distribution: they can't be executed in the browser.

See here for an announcement: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/psychopy3-launch-event-online-experiments-and-new-experiment-server/4721

Questions at this level (i.e. not specific code problems) are better suited to be taken to the community at https://discourse.psychopy.org rather than here at StackOverflow, which is oriented towards answering code questions that other people might find useful.